# How should I update from Task the UI Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, task

I have a task that performing some heavy work.
I need to path it's result to `LogContent`

```
Task<Tuple<SupportedComunicationFormats, List<Tuple<TimeSpan, string>>>>.Factory
    .StartNew(() => DoWork(dlg.FileName))
    .ContinueWith(obj => LogContent = obj.Result);
```

This is the property:

```
public Tuple<SupportedComunicationFormats, List<Tuple<TimeSpan, string>>> LogContent
{
    get { return _logContent; }
    private set
    {
        _logContent = value;
        if (_logContent != null)
        {
            string entry = string.Format("Recognized {0} log file",_logContent.Item1);
            _traceEntryQueue.AddEntry(Origin.Internal, entry);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that `_traceEntryQueue` is data bound to UI, and of cause I will have exception on code like this.

So, my question is how to make it work correctly?

Comment: What kind of UI do you use? WPF, Windows Forms, Silverlight, Web?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run the ContinueWith -task on the UI thread. This can be accomplished using the TaskScheduler of the UI thread with the [overloaded version of the ContinueWith -method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194761.aspx), ie.

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.Current;
...ContinueWith(obj => LogContent = obj.Result), CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, scheduler)
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a good article: [Parallel Programming: Task Schedulers and Synchronization Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx).

Take a look at [Task.ContinueWith() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991174.aspx).

Example:

```
var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
var task = new Task<TResult>(() =>
    {
        TResult r = ...;
        return r;
    });

task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        // Update UI (and UI-related data) here: success status.
        // t.Result contains the result.
    },
    CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, context);

task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        AggregateException aggregateException = t.Exception;
        aggregateException.Handle(exception => true);
        // Update UI (and UI-related data) here: failed status.
        // t.Exception contains the occured exception.
    },
    CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, context);

task.Start();
```

Since .NET 4.5 supports `async`/`await` keywords (see also [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)):

```
try
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() => GetResult());
    // Update UI: success.
    // Use the result.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Update UI: fail.
    // Use the exception.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Dispatcher` to invoke code on UI thread. Take a look at the article [Working With The WPF Dispatcher](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using async/await, then here is some example code that shows how to schedule a task to run on the GUI thread. Place this code at the bottom of the stack of all of your async/await calls to avoid the WPF runtime throwing errors with code not executing on the GUI thread.

Works with WPF + MVVM, tested under VS 2013.

```
public async Task GridLayoutSetFromXmlAsync(string gridLayoutAsXml)
{
    Task task = new Task(() => // Schedule some task here on the GUI thread );
    task.RunSynchronously();
    await task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was trying to achieve. A simple way to run a method async but still be able to update the main thread. I played around with Await Task.Run() but got nothing.

Comment: Word of warning - `Task.Run` is a heavyweight operation, it creates a new thread and gobbles up a lot of stack space. Use sparingly.